# Error: showing Invalid Version @openzeppelin/contracts

Tags: npm, package, openzeppelin

**while downloading openzeppelin package it is showing invalid version

**
`npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`

error:-

```
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:.npm/_logs/2024-03-25T19_53_35_145Z-debug-0.log
```

i have tried reading official documentation also but still i didn't got my solution